# How to make css jQuery thumbnail slides loop

Tags: css

So I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/RaV3u/5/

...but haven't been able to figure out how to make the slides loop -- that is, when the last slide finishes, it continues from the first, and the same for the first slide going backwards.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

```
/* THUMBNAIL SLIDER IMAGES 
------------------------------------------- */

.slideshow {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /* Change this value to slide */
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300%;
    z-index: -1; /* send this layer behind the .circle layer */
}


/* THUMBNAIL SLIDER NAVIGATION 
------------------------------------------- */

.thumb-slide-nav-wrapper {
    margin: 70px 15px; /* position of the nav buttons */
    overflow:auto;
}

.circle-left {
    /* position of the nav buttons */
    float:left;
}

.circle-right {
    /* position of the nav buttons */
    float:right;
}

.circle {
    /* nav buttons */
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: green;
}

a .circle:hover {
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[## `Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/RaV3u/7/)

---

In Your JavaScript Just check whether the end (`first` or `last` image) is reached before sliding it.

To get total count of images use: `var tot=$(".images").find("img").length;`

and use a counter variable `i` to check the `direction` of sliding and `end image reached or not` condition.

So here is your changed JS/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var tot=$(".images").find("img").length; //total images in slider nav
    var i=0; //acts as a counter
    var thumbSliderPos = $(".images").css("left");

    // Detect thumbnail nav button clicks

    $('#circle-left').click(function() {
        //Detect if first image is reached?
        if(i<=0){
        i=tot-2;
        $(".images").animate({
            "left": "-="+(400*i),
        }, 400);
        //Yes Show last image
       }
        else
        {
        $(".images").animate({
            left: "+=400",
        }, 400);
        i--;
        }
    });

    $('#circle-right').click(function() {
        //Detect if last image is reached?
        if(i>=tot-2)
        {
        $(".images").animate({
            left: "0",
        }, 400);
        i=0;
         //Yes Show first image
        }
        else
        {
        $(".images").animate({
            left: "-=400",
        }, 400);
         i++;
       }
    });


});
```

---

To make it `autoSlide` after page `loads` Here is another:

[## `Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/RaV3u/10/)

---

Hope it Helps you. Cheers :) !